# Can a module have the same artifactID as parent ? | Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project of following structure:

```
parent (artifactID: ABC)
 |
 |---- module 1 (artifactID: ***)
 |---- module 2 (artifactID: XYZ)
```

Can `module 1` have `artifactID: ABC`?

My parent module is only meant to package the modules together. It doesn't have any source code of its own.

Does Maven take into account the hierarchy of modules to distinguish two modules? If not why?
It shouldn't be difficult to distinguish two guys with the same name but in different places.

Comment: And the same `groupId` as the parent?

Comment: yes, same `groupId` as well as `artifactId`

Comment: Simple answer is probably no. `(groupId, artifactId)` is the combination that makes an artifact unique. You can also think of many ways something like that could go wrong...

Comment: The combination of groupId + artifactId must be unique ..simply....

Comment: In your example I would name the parent atifactId: `parent` ...cause it shows it's intention...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `groupId` is identical, the `artifactId` must be different.

As the maven [docs](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_project) state, the `groupId` has to be universally unique and the `artifactId` must be unique within the `groupId`.

**`groupId`**

> A universally unique identifier for a project. It is normal to use a fully-qualified package name to distinguish it from other projects with a similar name

**`artifactId`**

> The identifier for this artifact that is unique within the group given by the group ID.

Answer (score 2):

Sure - if the groupId is different :)

If the GAV is the same, then the artifact is the same and therefore your parent and artifact would be overwriting each other if you deploy them to say Artifactory or Nexus

Comment: No they won't overwrite. In Maven you won't get build this kind of setup. This build will fail....